# laravel generate PDF from blade

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am trying to download my page in pdf format and I have been following this tutorial step by step to do it. I tried using a sample data to do it and it work but when I try to use my own data it keep giving me undefined $data3, $object, ..

But I have already defined them already in my controller already:

testController

```
     public function getTestdata($id){
           $user = PersonalInfo::find($id);
          $object = PersonalInfo::where('id',$id)->get();
        $object1 = AdditionalInformation::where('user_id',$id)->get(); 
         $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
     return view('test',compact('id','object','object1','user','data3'));
 }
```

test.blade.php

```
<a href="{{  url('/pdf')  }}">Download PDF</a>
...
<th>
      @foreach($data3 as $currentUser)
      <img src="{{ url('images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}">
      @endforeach
 </th>
...
  @php
    $userFamily = $user->userFamily;
  @endphp
    <tr>
    <td><b>FAMILY Members</b></td>
      <td>
    @foreach($userFamily as $val)

    @if($val["meta_key"] == "relationshiplist")
    {{  $val["meta_value"]  }}  |
    @endif
        @endforeach
    </td>
```

DownloadPDFController:

```
public function fun_pdf(){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('test'); //load view page
    return $pdf->download('test.pdf'); // download pdf file
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/pdf', 'pdfDownloadController@fun_pdf');
Route::get('/user/showtest/{id}/test1', 'testController@getTestData')->name('template');
```

I also tried following this website to do but it does't seem to work as well, instead it gave me undefined $id. http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-generate-pdf-from-html-view-file-and-download-using-dompdfexample.html

If possible could you guys guide me on how to generate the PDF file

Comment: which error is coming?

Answer (score 5):

For this first, you should install Dompdf plugin https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

and everything else in its documentation

I think you should update the controller like this and pass id parameter, change the route also

```
    public function fun_pdf($id){
        $user = PersonalInfo::find($id);
        $object = PersonalInfo::where('id',$id)->get();
        $object1 = AdditionalInformation::where('user_id',$id)->get(); 
        $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
        $data =[
            'id' => $id,
            'object' => $object,
            'object1' => $object1,
            'user' => $user,
            'data3' => $data3,
        ];

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('test',$data); //load view page
        return $pdf->download('test.pdf'); // download pdf file
    }
```

Comment: Wait isn't this the same as mine? The problem I facing now is when I download, it return me undefined $data3 and test.blade.php can be viewed so the problem might be in the downloadPDFController I think

Comment: just changed the answer again update the route also for passing id

Comment: I did what you asked me and I changed the view to have this, <a href="{{  url('/pdf'/'.$id->id)  }}">Download PDF</a> and the route to this, Route::get('/pdf/{id}', 'pdfDownloadController@fun_pdf'); But I am getting this error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'images' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Should I change all to $data in my test.blade.php?

Comment: <img src="{{ asset('images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}"> don't know if correct anyway try this

Comment: I am getting this now, Trying to get property of non-object , pointing to the part where $user is in the test.blade.php, it seem like it giving null value from $data

Comment: It means you are using an undefined field name or relation. check user_image table has a field - 'name'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160676/discussion-between-dkna-and-rahul-reghunath).

Comment: Do you get the answer

Comment: Nope, but just now when I was using your code it was able to download the pdf but when I try it again it gave back the same error. It ok, i think there might be something wrong with my database so I was planning to redo the database part and try it again

Comment: Is there anyway to get the id other than like this? Because everytime i dd the id it return me pdf

Comment: I got f"open(/Users/omni/test/storage/fonts//material-icons-normal_a83785ccbfc5713b63b97bbf71e6fa23.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory" someone know why??